# How do I optimise my code to run for large values also

Tags: python

Below is my code.For small values it returns me correct answer What I am doing here is find the minimum difference between any two numbers such that it does not form a negative value.
Actually the input lines are cost for each year and I need to find the minimum loss (yes, it has to be a loss only).
When the input is large say 20000 numbers I get a timeout error.
Here is the link to the test case:https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/27771/input12.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1502978445&Signature=vKwJ0MC3G1U3DXKE1N0qSruD5EI%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

first line contains number of values and the subsequent lines contain the values.

```
#!/bin/python

import sys

number = long(raw_input().strip())
cost=map(long,raw_input().strip().split())
flag=1
j=0
mincost=max(cost)

print (mincost)

while j < number:
  k=j+1
  while k<number:
    if mincost>abs(cost[j] - cost[k]) and cost[j]> cost[k]:
      mincost=abs(cost[j] - cost[k])
    k+=1
  j+=1

print mincost
```

Comment: What exactly does it mean "does not form a negative number"?

Comment: This means that the difference should not be less than 0.The real problem statement involves each of the following values as a house's cost over the years.The problem involves the minimum cost such that I sell it for the minimum loss.(should be a loss).     eg:test case:3
5 10 3 here the house can be sold at 5-3=2 PS: the first 3 is the number of values suceeding it.

Answer (score 2):

For 20,000 numbers, you have (20,000 x 19,999)/2 = 199,990,000 pairwise comparisons. This is O(n^2) complexity. However, if you sort the values, the minimum difference will occur between two adjacent numbers. Since sorting is O(n log n), you can improve your algorithm by (a) sorting the values, and then (b) finding the minimum difference between successive pairs.

```
costs = [5, 4, 1, 8, 12]

sorted_costs = sorted(costs)
pairs = zip(sorted_costs[:-1], sorted_costs[1:])
differences = map(lambda (a, b): b - a, pairs)

print(min(differences)) # 1
```

The only question that remains is whether you could achieve the same result in O(n) time. Reducing the sorting to O(n) is possible (with a potentially huge space complexity) if your values are integers:

```
costs = [5, 4, 1, 8, 12]

min_cost = min(costs)
max_cost = max(costs)

flag_list = [False] * (max_cost - min_cost + 1)
for cost in costs:
    flag_list[cost - min_cost] = True

sorted_costs = [i + min_cost for i, b in enumerate(flag_list) if b]
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you import sys ? what's the use of 'flag' ?
if you have enough RAM, I would do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
number = 20000
cost = np.random.rand(number) * 1e6 # just for the example
current_min = 1e10 # just for the example
for i,j in enumerate(cost):
    diff = j-cost[i+1:]
    pos = diff > 0
    if pos.any():
        temp = np.min(diff[pos])
        if temp<current_min:
            current_min = temp
print(final estimation: ',current_min)
```